# Swift change heightAnchor programatically (no storyboard)

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new in swift, recently I want to change my heightAnchor programmatically. I have looked up some solutions on stack overflow but most of them are using IBOutlet in storyboard. My question is, if there exists a constraint already, is there any simple way to just update a new constraint?

for example

```
something.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
something.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true // original constraint
something.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true // want to override this one
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to original constraint, hold a strong reference to it and update its constant value directly

declare a variable as

```
var somethingWidthConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint? = nil
```

and wherever you are setting this constraint originally, hold a strong reference to it

```
self.somethingWidthConstraint = something.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
self.somethingWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

whenever you need to change its constant simply say

```
self.somethingWidthConstraint?.constant = 100
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

In order for your view to accept this value and update its frame immediately (without having to wait for next UI render cycle), you might have to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` and if you wanna animate this change you can always wrap it inside `UIView.animate`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Thats all

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the old constraint to false before setting the new one.

```
something.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
something.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
something.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = false 
something.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```